# post to slack api with httpotion elixir

Tags: api, post, elixir

Just dealing with a syntax error here. Trying to send the payload in the body of the `HTTPotion` request. Trying to send the data as json, but not really sure where I'm going wrong.

```
HTTPotion.post "https://hooks.slack.com/services/a00000/b0000/XXXXXXX", [body: "{'channel': '#general', 'username': 'thedanotto', 'text': 'Pokemon are scary!', 'icon_emoji': ':ghost:'}", ["Content-Type": "application/json"]]
```

=>  `** (SyntaxError) iex:1: syntax error before: '['`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing `headers:` before the headers list. This should work:

```
HTTPotion.post "https://hooks.slack.com/services/a00000/b0000/XXXXXXX", [body: "{'channel': '#general', 'username': 'thedanotto', 'text': 'Pokemon are scary!', 'icon_emoji': ':ghost:'}", headers: ["Content-Type": "application/json"]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing `headers` key

It should be like this:

```
HTTPotion.post "https://hooks.slack.com/services/a00000/b0000/XXXXXXX", [body: "{'channel': '#general', 'username': 'thedanotto', 'text': 'Pokemon are scary!', 'icon_emoji': ':ghost:'}", headers: ["Content-Type": "application/json"]]
```