# Posting to Slack API Elixir

Tags: elixir, slack-api

I am trying to post to the slack api using HTTPotion. I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38602879/post-to-slack-api-with-httpotion-elixir) question about it and it pointed me in the right direction but I kept getting the error:

```
HTTPotion.Response{body: "invalid_payload",
...
```

My code is

```
HTTPotion.post "https://hooks.slack.com/services/T00000000/B0000000/xxxxxxxxxxxxx", [body: "{'channel': '#elixir', 'username': 'elixir stuff', 'text': '#{text}'", headers: ["Content-Type": "application/json"]]
```

I am not really sure what is wrong with my payload

Any help would be great

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because your `body` is not valid JSON as it uses single quotes instead of double quotes and also does not escape the value of `text` properly. You should use a proper JSON encoder like [`poison`](https://github.com/devinus/poison) for this. After adding `poison` as a dependency, you can do:

```
body: Poison.encode!(%{channel: "#elixir", username: "elixir stuff", text: text}), ...
```